# Regular Expression In Order To Identify Tor Domains

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-requests, tor

I am working on a scraper that goes through html code trying to scrape tor domains. However I am having trouble coming up with a piece of code to match tor domains.

Tor domains are typically in the format of:

http://sitegoeshere.onion

or

https://sitegoeshere.onion

I just want to match urls that would be contained within a page, in the format  http://sitetexthere.onion or https://sitehereitis.onion. This is within a bunch of text that may not be urls. It should just pull out the urls.

I am sure there is an easy or good piece of regex that'll do this but I have not been able to find one. If anyone is able to link one or quickly spin one up that'd be muchos appreciated. Many thanks.

```
    session = requests.session()
    session.proxies = {}
    session.proxies['http'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'
    session.proxies['https'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'
    r = session.get('http://facebookcorewwwi.onion')
    print(r.text)
```

Comment: What do you mean by match? Do you just want to see if it ends with `onion`?

Comment: yeah pretty much, i just want to match urls that would be contained within a page, in the format  http://sitetexthere.onion or https://sitehereitis.onion. This is within a bunch of text that may not be urls. It should just pull out the urls.

Comment: A TOR domain is the first half of the base32 encoded SHA-1 hash of a public key, from a 1024-bit RSA key pair with the suffix “.onion”.
The result is that a .onion domain name will be 16 characters long and can only contain lowercase letters a to z and the digits 2 through 7. [source](https://www.expressvpn.com/blog/how-to-create-a-onion-address/)

Answer (score 2):

The `regex.match` will return `None` if the URL isn't matched.

```py
import re

regex = re.compile(r"^https?\:\/\/[\w\-\.]+\.onion")

url = 'https://sitegoes-here.onion'

if regex.match(url):
  print('Valid Tor Domain!')
else:
  print('Invalid Tor Domain!')
```

For optional http(s):

```py
regex = re.compile(r"^(?:https?\:\/\/)?[\w\-\.]+\.onion")
```

Comment: So i've used this and it's not able to find results for it? For instance the following strings are not matching:         https://static.xx.fbcdn23dssr3jqnq.onion/rsrc.php/v3/y4/r/-PAXP-deijE.gif and https://pixel.facebookcorewwwi.onion

Comment: So you don't want to match URLs with `http(s)` part?

Comment: I mean also those urls, but ones with and without would both be good

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer to add the regex for matching with optional `http(s)`.

Answer (score 0):

Regex patterns are mostly standard, so, i would recommend you this pattern:

'.onion$'

Backslash escapes the dot, and '$' character means the end of string. Since all urls starts with 'http(s)://' there's no need to including it in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are taken from href attributes you could try an attribute = value selector with $ ends with operator

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

resp = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_(anonymity_network)")  #example url. Replace with yours.
soup = bs(resp.text,'lxml')
links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('[href$=".onion"]')]
```